# Cell spacing, insets rect in collectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm struggling to understand how the cell size, insert, ect work in a collectionview.

for example, my collectionview is 160 high, my cell is 100 high, i put top and bottom inset to 30 and i can no longer see my cell when the app is run?

when ever i change these values sightly something happens to my cell size.

[image]

[image]

[image]

all i want to be able to do is lock that cell vertically in the centre of the collectionview.  I'm about to give up on interface builder altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I try this and I can not reproduce the same problem ,but if you still has problem one hack way is to set your collection view in other UIView and make collectionView height 100px with top and bottom constraint 30px and full sized cell 100px in collection view